# an Optimal control problem : infinite time horizon and free end point

Tags: dynamical-systems, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control, large-deviation-theory

i've never worked on optimal control problem before and have an issue with this problem :

Let $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^2_+$ and a constant $\lambda \neq0$ be fixed.
  I want to minimize,
$\qquad$ over final time $T>0$,
$\qquad$ over absolutely continuous trajectories $x(\cdot)$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ with $x(0)=x_0$, $x(T)=z$
  the cost function

$\qquad \qquad  J_T(x;z) =    
\displaystyle \sup_{\theta = (\theta_1,\theta_2) \in  \mathcal{C}^\infty\left([0,T];\mathbb{R^2}\right) }    \int_0^T \left[  \langle x'(t)\:,\: \theta(t)\rangle\: - \:  \lambda(e^{\theta_1(t)}-1)\\
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad - x_1(t)x_2(t)(e^{\theta_2(t)-\theta_1(t)}-1) -  x_2(t)(e^{-\theta_2(t)}-1)\right] dt$

where 
$z$ is left free in some convex but unbounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^2_+$.

**My questions are :**
**1)** can we have the sufficient conditions for optimality ? 
   i mean could we prove that there exist  $\qquad x^*$, $T^*$ and $z^*$ so that
        $\qquad  \qquad \qquad J_{T^*}(x^*;z^*) \leq J_T(x;z)$  $\qquad \forall \: x,z,T$

**2)** Assuming optimality, that is $\displaystyle \inf_{x,z,T} J_T(x;z) <+\infty$,
do we have
$\displaystyle \qquad \qquad \lim_{||z||\to +\infty} \inf_{x,T} J_T(x;z) = +\infty$ ?

I know that this could sound very abstract or perhaps a little ambiguous.
in my context,  the initial value
$\qquad x_0\quad $ is a stable attractor ( of dynamical system)
  $\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \left\{
  \begin{array}{lcl}
   y_1'(t) &=& \lambda - y(t)y_2(t)\\
   y_1'(t) &=& y_1(t)y_2(t) - y_2(t)
   \end{array}
  \right.$
 $\qquad z\quad $ are target points on the boundary of the attraction domain of $x_0$
$\qquad J_T(x;z)$ is the energy needed to go from $x_0$ (the attractor) to $z$ (at the boundary of attraction domainn) by following the trajectory $x$.

Noting that (integration by part : x(T) =  z and x(0)=x_0 )
$\qquad \qquad  J_T(x;z) =    
\displaystyle \sup_{\theta = (\theta_1,\theta_2) \in  \mathcal{C}^\infty\left([0,T];\mathbb{R^2}\right) }\Bigg\{  \langle z\:,\:\theta(T)\rangle -  \langle x_0\:,\:\theta(0)\rangle  - \int_0^T  \langle x(t)\:,\: \theta'(t)\rangle\:dt\\
 \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad - \int_0^T \lambda(e^{\theta_1(t)}-1) - x_1(t)x_2(t)(e^{\theta_2(t)-\theta_1(t)}-1) -  x_2(t)(e^{-\theta_2(t)}-1) \: dt\Bigg\}$

I really want to know if the more $z$ is far away from $x_0$ the more the energy to reach it from $x_0$ would be important? that's the aim of my question 2).  Or perhaps i can have a condition that implies it?
For me it seems reasonable to imagine that  if the energy to go from $x_0$
 to the boundary is finished, the optimal trajectory could not  be  too far from $x_0$ ??

The problem can be rewrite  as classical Bolza optimal control problem.
i could give the representation if it could help.

Any book which can help?? Thanks in advance !!!